# ZRAM enabled but Swap in RAM not used

Tags: swap, zram

So I've just decided to enable **zram** on my 6 GB ram Ubuntu 12.04, using **zram-config**.
It takes about 2.9 GB of ram (after manually starting up the service, fixing this later...), but, even with different values of *swappiness*, it SAYS that there's about 3 GB of swap, but never use it.
And I've already rebooted.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

What are you asking?

If you have 6GB of RAM then I doubt any paging is needed.

Do you want to page everything out for no reason?

Nothing gets paged until RAM needs to be freed, which it probably doesn't.